# Jmeter request works on local but getting 401 on distributed testing on VMS

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, software-quality

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78iBy.png)I have a jmeter login script,,,i send 2 requests, 1 is login -options where i get the cookie and save in a header variable,,second request is the login -post request which has credentials as payload and i also set the cookie from previus req and send as a header,,the script works well in local,but when i upload to master vm and test with slave i get 401 errors

since it it working on local,is there something i should add on vms?,also on local if i remove the header i also start getting the 401,so im guessing its something to do with the header:cookie

Comment: Also im able to send other requests the logins specifically are the ones returning 401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can it be the case you didn't set `CookieManager.save.cookies` property to `true` on the slave machine? If not please do so because each slave has its own configuration and looking into your HTTP Header Manager setup you're relying on a cookie stored in the HTTP Cookie Manager and the aforementioned property needs to be set to `true` in order to make this approach work.

More information:

- [Miscellaneous configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager)

Another [limitation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode) could be:

> `Stripped` mode family strips `responseData` so this means that some Elements that rely on the previous `responseData` being available will not work.
> This is not really a problem as there is always a more efficient way to implement this feature.

However I don't think it's your case.

Comment: CookieManager.save.cookies property to true,,,,This was the issue thanks